# JQuery - Animate div to mouse coords

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, mouseevent

I am trying to send a div to some mouse coords I get when the mouse is clicked. The first part, where I get the mouse coords works fine - I am just having difficulty creating the animate part.

```
$("#container").click(function(e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

   console.log (relX);
   console.log (relY);

  $("#move").animate({left: 'relX', top: 'relY'});

});
```

CSS:

```
#container {
width: 500px;
height 500px;
}

#move {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-color: #000;
position : absolute;
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: Should `$("#move").animate({left: 'relX', top: 'relY'});` be `$("#move").animate({left: relX, top: relY});`? You want left and top properties to have the actual value, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

$("#move").animate({left: 'relX', top: 'relY'});

to

$("#move").animate({left: relX, top: relY});

Answer (score 2):

Like guys mentioned, I add example on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/E64TK/

also in css you forgot **":"**

```
#container {
   width: 500px;
   height{here} 500px;
}
```